# Getting around a WAF's restrictions for SQLi

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I have this payload: `AND SELECT SUBSTR(table_name,1,1) FROM information_schema.tables > 'A'`

but a WAF restricts `table_name` and `information_schema` keywords and gives a `not acceptable` message.

Is there is a way to get around this and retrieve table names?

note : already tried table name bruteforcing.

Comment: Maybe you could try some of the WAF bypass features in SQLmap?

Comment: @multithr3at3d none of them works